# How to store a dataframe object between API calls?

Tags: python, django

My Django app will allow the users to upload an Excel file and will then analyze and visualize data in this file.

To handle the Excel files, I have introduced a model with `FileField`:

```
class DataFile(models.Model)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='data_files')
```

Next, I want to create some API views for this app that would take the file uploaded by user, manipulate it with Pandas' `dataframe` object and return the manipulated data.

For example:

```
def some_api_view(request):
    data_file = DataFile.objects.last()
    dataframe = pandas.read_excel(data_file.file.path)
    manipulated_dataframe = # ... dataframe manipulation goes on here ... #
    return JsonResponse({'manipulated_dataframe': manipulated_dataframe'})
```

My concern is that each API view like this will need to read the Excel file on its own. Is it possible to design the API in a way that would allow reading the file into a dataframe only once (since it will always be the same file), and then the API views would only be responsible for retrieving this dataframe, manipulating it and returning manipulated data?

I am using an SQL database, so I cannot store the dataframe object itself in the database. Also, I would rather avoid pickling it and storing the pickle in a field.

Comment: There is no clean solution, I think. If you do not want to pickle and save it to the SQL database, you can use memcached or redis to cache it. But it will be pickled automatically or you will have to pickle it manually anyway because the cache can store only primitive data types.

Comment: if there are not much dataframes then you can store objects in session or some global dictionary for excel file dataframes. however, this is a really bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the excel file in the API view, you can define a function the Model which returns a Dataframe.

```
class DataFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='data_files')
    #Other fields here

    def get_dataframe(self): 
        dataframe = pandas.read_excel(self.file.path)
        return dataframe
```

Call this function for the required object.